# How to nest 2 span4's inside a span8 with padding - and keep them side by side (not stacked)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a span8 - with 2 nested span4:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="span8 content-left">
<div class="padder-big place-details">

<div class="span4">
   hello
</div>

<div class="span4>
   bye
</div>

</div></div></div>
```

There is padding in the big span8 - so obviously the 2 span4's stack on top of each other - I would like them side by side.

How can I make them sit side by side and stay aligned to the underlying grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have additional horizontal padding in the container then by definition the content can not be aligned in the (same) grid anymore which is why the content gets stacked. You should remove the extra padding (maybe move it into the `span4` elements) or create your own customized `span4` style that takes your extra padding into account.

Alternatively you could try adding `row-fluid` attribute on the `div.place-details` (and adjust the inner spans to "50%" so to speak), e.g.

```
<div class="padder-big place-details row-fluid">

<div class="span6">
   hello
</div>

<div class="span6">
   bye
</div>

</div>
```

see [Fluid grid system](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem)

Comment: Thanks - pointed me the right direction. 'padder-big' needs to be in <div>'s nested inside the span6's though - otherwise the span's stack. (or have I missed something?)